# Android vertical ScrollView doesn't work at all

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have been stuck on this problem adjusted the `android:layout_height/width` a lot, but I can't seem to see why it's not working. I looked up more questions like mine, but those don't seem to work for me.

`XML`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="nl.melvinsterk.android.medicatieapplicatie.TreatmentActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/been"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblDoctersNotes" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Proxycozynas"
            android:id="@+id/tvTreatmentMedicine"
            android:width="160dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Nog maar X dagen"
            android:id="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="77dp"
            android:width="140dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />


        <View
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:onClick="sideEffectsOnClick"
            android:text="Last van bijwerkingen?"
            android:id="@+id/lblSideEffects"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_next"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewSeperator"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewSeperator"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <View
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblSideEffects"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:onClick="howToOnClick"
            android:text="Hoe neem ik mijn medicatie?"
            android:id="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblSideEffects"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblSideEffects" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_next"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator2"
            android:layout_above="@+id/viewSeperator4"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvHowToMedication" />

        <View
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Doktersnotitie"
            android:id="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Doktersnotitie komt hier"
            android:id="@+id/tvDoctorsnote"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <View
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator3"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDoctorsnote"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Gebruiksaanwijzing"
            android:id="@+id/lblMedicineInstruction"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medicijn instructies komen hier"
            android:id="@+id/tvMedicineInstruction"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblMedicineInstruction"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: He wont show my Coordinator layout which is there but not showing up

Comment: thanks i didnt know that was possible this is actually the first time i tried to ask a question myself been stuck a couple of hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try after adding the namespace xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to the ScrollView.

Comment: that didnt fix the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

**Try to implement those `TextViews` or whatever in:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

       <!-- your content -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Or with your codes, Something like this:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/been" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTreatmentMedicine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
                android:width="160dp"
                android:text="Proxycozynas"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="77dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:width="140dp"
                android:text="Nog maar X dagen"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeperator"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblSideEffects"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvTreatmentRemainingDays"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:onClick="sideEffectsOnClick"
                android:text="Last van bijwerkingen?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewSeperator"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewSeperator"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_next" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeperator2"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblSideEffects"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblSideEffects"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblSideEffects"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:onClick="howToOnClick"
                android:text="Hoe neem ik mijn medicatie?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/viewSeperator4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator2"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_next" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeperator4"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvHowToMedication"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator4"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Doktersnotitie"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDoctorsnote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblDoctersNotes"
                android:text="Doktersnotitie komt hier"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewSeperator3"
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvDoctorsnote"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblMedicineInstruction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewSeperator3"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Gebruiksaanwijzing"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMedicineInstruction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblMedicineInstruction"
                android:text="Medicijn instructies komen hier"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: With the RelativeLayout in between it or not?

Comment: @Rawbb - you were doing it in wrong way and the problem was in the `RelativeLayout`.Also, **i'd rather to use `NestedScrollView` since you are using Support Library** ;)

Comment: I did try using NestedScrollView but even now this XML code isnt working for me, whenever i try to use NestedScrollView it pushes all the textviews within eachother

Comment: after adding my textviews, etc. I am not able to scroll anymore but it does  work when testing with a textview. I'm using an emulator to debug. The only difference is that i load the code from an API instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Yeah, that has to be like that, try to use these codes(**LinearLayout code and contents**) in your layout: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/ if the LinearLayout items worked, Your implementation has a problem then,  you need to fix them.F.g: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14499212/ and that returns your skills and you really need to read the docs about `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` and the relationship between these.By the way, this thread would be ended with my answer i guess because your main problem is fixed so far.